# Why won't Heroku accept my Gemfile.lock in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, heroku

I have a rails application that I deploy on Heroku. I'm using several different machines, and I noticed that when I add new dependencies (so that `Gemfile.lock` is rebuilt) and do `bundle install` on my Windows computer at home, push to Heroku fails with the following error:

```
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.
   You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
   the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control
   ...
```

`Gemfile.lock` IS under version control, but Heroku appearently chooses to ignore it since it's created in Windows, and then complains that it's missing seconds later. Why does this happen? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Something to do with CR/LF on Windows vs *nix?

Comment: Maybe? Judging from the output from the failed push, it looks like Heroku is deliberately ignoring it.

Comment: Is bundler perhaps choosing precompiled windows binaries as dependencies and listing them in `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Have a look at the question "Does Bundler work on Windows?" here: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/bundler-pro-tip/ it looks like it could be related to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like matt commented above:

The problem is that Bundler creates different `Gemfile.lock`s for Windows. The only solution is to create and commit the lock file on a *NIX system.

I would suggest to create a virtual machine running e.g. [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com) – maybe using [Virtual Box](http://virtualbox.org). You can even get ready-to-use virtual machines – for example [here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/).

Comment: Is there really no other way? That's pretty absurd. The Heroku folks should at least have this in their docs. I couldn't find anything about it. Thank you very much for the answer - it cleared things up!

Comment: I just had same issue, still nothing in the documents. Very odd, and does make it look like heroku just isn't interested in windows users using their service.

Comment: and this is the reason i don't use linux very often. there's a million ways to do things, and if you don't pick the right way then you're screwed.. no standards amongst developers.

Answer (score 24):

I fixed mine by opening Gemfile.lock and deleting the following two lines:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

So now i just need to make a script that bundles then removes that from the lock file.

Comment: It's also worth looking through for any windows version of gems that sneaked into your Gemfile.lock. (eg. ...-x86-mingw32)

Comment: This answer is best, thank you- struggled for an hour this morning, deleting this line worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that did the trick, extra beers for you my friend

Answer (score 4):

From the [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler):

> If the platforms section of your Gemfile contains Windows entries,
>   such as **mswin** or **mingw**, then the Gemfile.lock file will be ignored.

Comment: This helped me. Had a Sqlite3 gem listed that was a mingw version, luckily it could be removed since i'm not using sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Just battled through this problem for a while.

I trimmed my gemfile back to just rails and still had the issue. Then, thinking that heroku had demanded an update of the heroku gem today, I looked closer at heroku changes.

It seems the 1.9.2 ruby "bamboo" stack is now the default one - my app is still running on the 1.8.7 stack. So I ran "heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2" and updated the stack to 1.9.2 - not something I wanted to do, but you know what, it fixed the issue above.

Of course, I didn't want to be on the 1.9.2 stack, so I migrated back down to the 1.8.7 stack, and things installed correctly again. So I think this is a workaround - and probably an overly complex one - but it seemed to "flush" whatever the error was heroku-side. As nothing I did locally (and I tried a LOT of things from StackOverflow articles) had any effect, the push just kept failing as above.

So yeah, this fixes it. Doesn't take too long either. But suspect a better workaround may be spotted by more heroku-knowledgeable developers !

Comment: Just got this issue again. Googled around. No answer fixed it - then ran through this before I even realised I was following my own post ! So yeah, still a mystery to me, but this is the only cure I could find to dodgy Gemfile.lock compliants...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you *commit* the changes to `Gemfile.lock` after installing the bundle. On your next `push` to Heroku, the new gems should be installed correctly.

Comment: `Genfile.lock` is commited. It doesn't help when I'm on Windows.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue.