# Heroku deployment issues

Tags: windows, deployment, heroku

I did couple test deployments on Heroku today from Windows box and noticed two issues.

When I run the `git push heroku master` heroku

1. Tells me "Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it" everytime I do the push
2. It installs every gem everytime I push even though the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock haven't changed

Looked around but don't seem to find anything meaningful on this issue.

I am on Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2p180

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954236/why-wont-heroku-accept-my-gemfile-lock-in-windows. There's an issue with using Bundler on windows and deploying to other platforms.

Comment: Not sure if this is related but have you installed pg and thin gems on production only?