# Heroku Rails Failed to install gems via Bundler - no specified source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'm getting some strange errors when trying to commit to Heroku... 
My gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
group :assets do
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
gem 'uglifier'
end

gem "jquery-rails"
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.6.7", :group => :test
gem "mongoid-rspec", ">= 1.4.4", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.1.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.0.2", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
gem "bson_ext", ">= 1.3.1"
gem "mongoid", ">= 2.2.0"
gem "paperclip"
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip" 
gem "devise", ">= 1.4.4"
gem "uuidtools"
gem "rqrcode"
gem "dynamic_form"
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'right_aws', :require => 'right_aws'
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
gem 'compass', :git => 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git'
gem 'html5-boilerplate', :git => 'git://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerplate.git'
```

My errors

```
Counting objects: 86, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 9.76 KiB, done.
Total 57 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc
    Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle
    You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
    updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
    If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze
    by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.
    You have added to the Gemfile:
    * source: git://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerplate.git (at maste
r)
    * source: git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git (at master)
    * source: rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
    * rails (= 3.1.0)
    * coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
    * uglifier
    * jquery-rails
    * rspec-rails (>= 2.6.1)
    * database_cleaner (>= 0.6.7)
    * mongoid-rspec (>= 1.4.4)
    * factory_girl_rails (>= 1.1.0)
    * cucumber-rails (>= 1.0.2)
    * capybara (>= 1.0.1)
    * launchy (>= 2.0.5)
    * bson_ext (>= 1.3.1)
    * mongoid (>= 2.2.0)
    * paperclip
    * mongoid-paperclip
    * devise (>= 1.4.4)
    * uuidtools
    * rqrcode
    * dynamic_form
    * aws-s3
    * right_aws
    * sass-rails (~> 3.1.0)
    * compass
    * html5-boilerplate
    You have changed in the Gemfile:
    * compass from `git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git (at master)` t
o `no specified source`
    * html5-boilerplate from `git://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerpla
te.git (at master)` to `no specified source`

!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
```

Stuff I've git rm Gemfile.lock then bundle install, git add . , git commit -m "heroku please work" and then git push. But no dice. I've also tried updating bundler (bundle version 1.0.21 on windows)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is `Gemfile.lock` in your `.gitignore` file? Did you commit after you did `git add`?

Comment: Did you `git commit` during your second try?

Comment: my git ignore file is just:
log/*
tmp/*
**/.tmp_*

Comment: @phoffer i did, i forgot to mention that, let me edit the post

Comment: I ran into this a few days ago when deploying to Heroku (Cedar stack), and I believe running `bundle install` again, then re-committing everything did the trick.

Comment: When you `git add .`, did you verify via `git status` that the update to `Gemfile.lock` had in fact been added and staged for commit?  Are you also pushing to another remote git repository (GitHub, etc.) where you can check to see whether the new `Gemfile.lock` (with appropriate commit message) has been pushed?  Just trying to follow and verify success at each stage up the "ladder" as a way of troubleshooting...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Need to run git add . and git commit after bundle install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after researching and experimenting with different suggested solutions for the past few days, I came across this post that helped me resolve it:

[Heroku rejecting push in mature application (pre-receive hook declined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740777/heroku-rejecting-push-in-mature-application-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Codeglot offers steps in the comments under his answer that may help you.

I was able to resolve my issue by running `gem update heroku`.  I then removed the older version of the heroku gem (`gem uninstall heroku -v 2.8.6`).  You can type `gem list` to see if you have multiple versions of the heroku gem installed.  When I then reran `bundle install` and re-pushed to heroku, it worked.

If that doesn't work for you, Codeglot provides the steps to nuke your app and start over, which seems to have worked for the person asking the question in that post.