# Rails and postgres - pg gem ignored during deploy on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have trouble deploying my app on heroku. I have added 'pg' gem to Gemfile, and even try to include something like   gem 'therubyracer-heroku'. 
during

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I get something like this:

```
>heroku rake db:migrate
 --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adap
ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connectio
n_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_conne
ction'
```

Another interesting part is that while pushing to heroku pg is not mentioned during bundle install operation like if it was ignored. I also watched the Gemfile.lock and pg is mentioned there to:

```
pg (0.11.0-x86-mingw32)
```

I wonder if it is a Windows gem issue that cause heroku to ignore the pg gem or something ?

Can anyone help or had similar problem ?

//EDIT

Seems related: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954236/why-wont-heroku-accept-my-gemfile-lock-in-windows)

And looks unsolveable

Comment: Is your up-to-date Gemfile & Gemfile.lock committed in source control?

Comment: Yes I do sth like this change gemfile run local bundle, then commit both and after that push gives me error `You have modified your Gemfile in development` so I change sth in .lock file like remove PLATFORMS section to be able to push

Comment: OK - That message is normally issued by Heroku when your Gemfile.lock is not up to date with what is in your Gemfile.  I would clone your repo to a new location and see what comes out just to check it's in git properly.

Failing that, contact Heroku support.

Answer (score 2):

In your Gemfile limit postgres to your production group;

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

rebundle

```
bundle --without production
```

and commit to git (Gemfile and Gemfile.lock) and push to Heroku. That should solve your problem.

Comment: ohhh.. does this limit is necessary ? nothing changed, same errors :/

Comment: I had done all this, except push the files to heroku via git, worked great, and my rake db:migrate works! Thanks.