# Doing a "heroku db:migrate" and getting the error "Please install the postgresql adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, migrate

I'm trying to do a heroku db:migrate with my mySQL database and I'm getting the error/suggestion:

Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

I try to put the "gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter" in my gem-file, but when I run bundle install, I get:

charlotte-dator:showwwdown holgersindbaek$ bundle install
/Users/holgersindbaek/Projekter/Showwwdown/showwwdown/Gemfile:34:in `evaluate': undefined local variable or method`activerecord' for # (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:138:in`definition'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in`send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in`start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19

Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822896/rails-and-postgres-pg-gem-ignored-during-deploy-on-heroku

Comment: Thank you. There seemed to be some help there. After I added gem 'pg' to my gemfile and ran bundle install, I forgot to commit and push to heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your gemfile (instead):

```
gem 'pg'
```

If you don't use Postgres in development, you can do this:

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
```

Comment: I'm using mySQL in development and even though i put "gem 'pg', :group => :production" in the gem-file, i still get: "rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)"

Comment: You must also re-bundle after making any changes to your `Gemfile`. You re-bundle by running the command `bundle`. After you re-bundle, add the `Gemfile.lock` to git and re-deploy to Heroku.

Comment: it's giving me the same error when running bundle, instead of bundle install.

Comment: Sorry.. didn't understand you at first. I should commit and push the files to heroku and then run db:migrate. Found the help in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822896/rails-and-postgres-pg-gem-ignored-during-deploy-on-heroku

Comment: `bundle` is the same as `bundle install`. You should always run `bundle` or `bundle update [gemname]` after updating your Gemfile. If you want Heroku to have the changes you make to your Gemfile, yes, you need to commit and push them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the branch you are pushing to heroku is master branch.

In my case i had tried all above & it was not working. I had done another mistake when i pushed my git repository i didn't push master branch but instead another 'named' branch. So my changes were not getting reflected even after updating gem file etc .

Comment: This was it. 2 hours wasted on a named branch. Thanks.