# Error in Gemfile with heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

I'm reading [this manual](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3athe_first_application) and when I try to deploy my first app git says:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * source: rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
       * rails (= 3.0.3)
       * sqlite3 (= 1.3.3)
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't deploy to Heroku very well from a Windows Rails installation.

It is telling you that you didn't commit the file right after saying it ignored the file, so the real question you're trying to answer is "why isn't Heroku accepting my Windows Gemfile.lock file?".  Based on that, I'd have pulled out "Windows Gemfile.lock detected; ignoring it" and pasted that into google or here in Stack Overflow.

That would have lead you to this previous SO answer:  [Why won't Heroku accept my Gemfile.lock in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954236/why-wont-heroku-accept-my-gemfile-lock-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you. I am installing VMWare and Ubuntu now.... then i will begin again with the book.